# prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden not working on iPhone X

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, iphone-x, home-button

I am currently updating one of my apps to iPhone X and tried to hide the home indicator on a fullscreen viewcontroller showing an image using:

```
override func prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

This method seems to do nothing, though. It is never called and the home indicator is never hidden, even after a while of inactivity. The simulator does seem to support this since the Photos app does hide the home indicator.

Is there some other flag that needs to be set to make this work? I tried it in multiple view controllers and none of them show the correct behaviour.

I also tried to add

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    self.setNeedsUpdateOfHomeIndicatorAutoHidden()
}
```

to my `viewDidLoad()` but to no avail

Comment: None of the solutions work for modal windows, maybe it's by design..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you show your `UIViewController` in `UINavigationController`, you have to override `childViewControllerForHomeIndicatorAutoHidden()` function:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    open override func childViewControllerForHomeIndicatorAutoHidden() -> UIViewController? {
        return topViewController
    }
}
```

Or if you show your `UIViewController` like subview of parent view controller, you also have to override this function and return child view controller.

Comment: worked for me, but I had to use `self.topViewController`

Comment: `-(BOOL)prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden
 {
    return self.shouldHideHomeIndicator;//YES
 }

-(UIViewController *)childViewControllerForHomeIndicatorAutoHidden 
{
    return self;
}`
@BeniaminSarkisian
 I have added this in my Objective C code. but not working

Comment: @S.Wei No. I have implemented that methods, but not working

Answer (score 3):

As per  [developer guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887510-prefershomeindicatorautohidden?language=objc) for **prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden** its clear that,

> The system takes your preference into account, but returning YES is no guarantee that the indicator will be hidden.

This method is only helpful if any of the objects are overlapping with the home indicator.

FYI, the home indicator will hide only after a couple of seconds, but it will reappear as soon as the user touches the screen.

Comment: while this is true, I know of no known circumstance where the system will currently ignore this setting during normal app use. In particular, I am using it in a very similar context to apple's own photos app. The problem was indeed, as mentioned above, that another method needs to be implemented when inside a navigation controller.

Answer (score 2):

Swift version of @Beniamin's answer:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    open override var childForHomeIndicatorAutoHidden: UIViewController? {
        return topViewController
    }
}
```