# Hide home button on iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, home-button

I have to figure out a way to hide the home button for all of my View controllers in the app.

Yes

```
override var prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
```

is an option but what if I have like 100 VCs, is this the only way?
I use navigation controller so I tried to override this property there, but it doesn't seems to have a reflection on the others as well.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can create a default base view controller class and all your VCs will be subclasses of it. in this base class you can control the `prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden `

Comment: Ofc... That is so simple.. Thanks man, I would've bounced my head all day long .. Guess my Java background didn't help much, thanks again!

Comment: here is a solution using extension that will override all VC in your case 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46776347/1806270